# The operator in Tensor algebra.

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.
We define the $k^{th}$ tensor power of $V$:
$$T^kV = V \otimes V \otimes ... \otimes V$$
We contruct $T(V)$ as the direct sum of $T^kV$ for $k=0,1,2,...$
$$T(V) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty T^kV = K \oplus V \oplus (V \otimes V) \oplus ...$$
The multiplication in $T(V)$ is determined by the canonical isomorphism
$$T^kV \oplus T^lV \rightarrow T^{k+l}V$$
given by the tensor product, which is then extended by linearity to all of $T(V)$.

Can you help me to explain more about this product in $T(V)$?

Let $\phi : T(V) \times T(V) \rightarrow T(V)$ be the multiplicative operator of $T(V)$.
And $(a, u_{11},u_{12} \otimes u_{22},...), \ (b, v_{11},v_{12} \otimes v_{22},...) \in T(V)$.

Then, how can we determine $\phi((a, u_{11},u_{12} \otimes u_{22},...), \ (b, v_{11},v_{12} \otimes v_{22},...))$ ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to know that tensor products commute with direct sums, and that they are associative, in particular there are isomorphisms $T^p(V) \otimes T^q(V) \cong T^n(V)$ when $p+q=n$. For fixed $n$, they induces a homomorphism $\bigoplus_{p+q=n} T^p(V) \otimes T^q(V) \to T^n(V)$. Then $\phi$ is defined as the composition of the following homomorphisms:

$$T(V) \otimes T(V) \cong \bigoplus_n \bigoplus_{p+q=n} T^p(V) \otimes T^q(V) \to \bigoplus_n T^n(V) = T(V)$$

Tracing back the definitions, we have

$$(v_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes v_p) \otimes (w_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes w_q) \mapsto v_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes v_p \otimes w_1 \otimes \dotsc \otimes w_q.$$

This describes $\phi$ completely. If $x=\sum_n x_n$ and $y=\sum_n y_n$ are arbitrary elements of $T(V)$, where $x_n,y_n \in T^n(V)$, then $\phi(x \otimes y)=\sum_{p,q} \phi(x_p \otimes y_q)$ since $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

The most important feature (and actually this is the definition) of the tensor algebra is its universal property. If $A$ is any algebra and $V \to A$ is a linear map, it extends uniquely to a homomorphism of algebras $T(V) \to A$. Thus, $T(-)$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from algebras to vector spaces.

For more on tensor products, you can look at Keith conrad's articles ([part 1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf), [part 2](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf)).

Comment: @ Martin: Thanks for your explain and article. It is really helpful for me.